# Update Azure Data Factory Properties for Datasets/Pipelines/Linked Services/Triggers using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

What is Power shell command for Updating Properties of either (datasets/Pipelines/Triggers) in Azure Data factory?

Ex: Set-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline - create/update a pipeline in Azure Data factory.

Incase Set-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline command can useful for updating pipeline, How can I set new name properties ?which parameter in this command suitable for renaming pipeline?

**But I want to know command which can update properties such as Pipeline Name/ Trigger Name /Dataset Name.**

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/?view=azps-5.1.0#data-factories), there is no update command about **Pipeline Name/ Trigger Name /Dataset Name**.

I think we have two ways to rename them.

1. Using powershell, we need to remove the resources first and then create it again.
   Here I take the pipeline as an example:

```
Remove-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -Name "<PipelineName>" -DataFactoryName "<DataFactoryName>"

Set-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -Name "<PipelineName>" -DataFactoryName "<DataFactoryName>" -File ".\***.json"
```

2. Using Azure Data Factory UI, we can rename them in place easily.
   Here I take the pipeline as an example:

[image]